# Bulk action in admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I used `bulkActions` props for [Admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) List but don't show anything when I select rows. How to can I use the bulk action?

```
const AccountingBulkActions = props => (
    <BulkActions {...props}>
        <BulkDeleteAction />
    </BulkActions>
);

export const AccountingList = (props) => (

    <List
        {...props}
        bulkActions={<AccountingBulkActions />}
        title="Accounting">
        <Datagrid
            headerOptions={{ adjustForCheckbox: true, displaySelectAll: true }}
            bodyOptions={{ displayRowCheckbox: true }}
            rowOptions={{ selectable: true }}
            options={{ multiSelectable: true }}>
            <DateField source="createdAt" />
            <TypeLabel source="type" />
            <GenderLabel source="gender" />
            <NumberField source="paymentPrice" />
            <NumberField source="totalPrice" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Comment: Can you confirm you're using react-admin and not admin-on-rest ?

Comment: @Gildas No, I'm using admin-on-rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk actions are a new feature only available on react-admin. You'll have to upgrade your admin-in-rest app.

Comment: In Datagrid tag headerOptions, bodyOptions, rowOptions and options worked and show gride checkbox tag. What are their uses?

Comment: Because they are passed on to material-ui components which support those options. However, there is no logic bound to them in `admin-on-rest`